# "Sub columns" in MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a project idea which would be much more simple if this exists;  Is it possible to create sub-columns in MySQL?

This is an example of what I mean, in table form:

```
+--------+---------------+
|        |    Weekday    |
|  Time  +-------+-------+
|        |  1ST  |  2ND  |
+--------+-------+-------+
| 8:00   | Jim   | Bob   |
| 9:00   | Steve | Jim   |
| 10:00  | Tod   | Rick  |
+--------+-------+-------+
```

I have to specify a primary and a secondary point of contact for every day of the week. I figured it would be very easy to have "Primary" and "Secondary" under Sunday, Saturday, etc.

A friend of mine suggested something like this would be possible, which led me to this quest.

Comment: what is the reason for this - it is not possible

Comment: Can you explain your use case so we might be able to suggest an alternative?

Comment: You can get the same thing with a join

Comment: Added the reason for the question in an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First think first that all of databases goal is about storing and manipulating data, whatever the type of database. And how data to be shown to user will be done on application level. On application level, data can be shown as table, grid, chart, or whatever you want.

I think you miss conception about this goal.

Comment: The idea was being able to pull queries for both primary and secondary individually, while also being able to pull each day as a whole, both with extremely simple queries. I can still achieve my goal with either slightly more complex queries or a more complex database. Either way, it was just a curiosity as to whether or not MySQL had this feature; a friend stated it did, but I had never heard of it before.