# Getting values from three tables using join and group by

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I'm having three tables, financial_years, house_details, consumer_details. I have added my schema in Sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd527d/2 and my expected result is wrapped because of its length given below. The query I have tried is.

Query:

```
SELECT c.consumer_name as Name
      ,c.house_number
      ,c.address
      ,sum(CASE WHEN h.subincome = 'Garbage tax' THEN f.garbage_tax else 0 end) - 
      sum(CASE WHEN h.subincome = 'Garbage tax' THEN h.rupees else 0 END) as gtax
      ,sum(CASE WHEN h.subincome = 'House tax' THEN f.house_tax else 0 end) - 
      sum(CASE WHEN h.subincome = 'House tax' THEN h.rupees else 0 END) as htax, 
      ,sum(CASE WHEN h.subincome = 'Light tax' THEN f.light_tax else 0 end) - 
      sum(CASE WHEN h.subincome = 'Light tax' THEN h.rupees else 0 END) as LTAX 
from house_details h 
INNER JOIN financial_year f ON h.financial_year = f.year 
                            AND h.house_id = f.house_number
INNER JOIN consumer_details c ON h.house_id = c.house_number 
                              AND h.financial_year != '2017-2018' 
GROUP BY c.consumer_name
        ,c.house_number
        ,c.address
```

Expected Result:

```
sid | name | house_no | address | arrears
---------------------------------------------------------------------
                                  house_tax | light_tax | garbage_tax
---------------------------------------------------------------------
22    Bala   22         Mumbai    145         710         450 
25    Kannan 25         Pune      704         803         630
2     Arul   2          Delhi     60          570         590

current                             | total
------------------------------------------------------------------------
house_tax | light_tax | garbage_tax | house_tax | light_tax | garbage_tax
------------------------------------------------------------------------
300         400         500           445         1110        950
550         567         543           1254        1370        1173
700         800         900           760         1370        1490

 receipt_no                            | collection
------------------------------------------------------------------------
house_tax  |  light_tax  | garbage_tax | house_tax | light_tax | garbage_tax
------------------------------------------------------------------------
312,313,314   309,310,311   288,304,308  400         540         484
407,408,409   404,405,406   401,402,403  921         915         905                                
410           -             -            500         0           0

 balance
------------------------------------
house_tax | light_tax | garbage_tax 
------------------------------------
45          570         466         
333         455         268         
260         1370        1490
```

Comment: Your expected result link does not work for me.  Please make this a complete question by showing us sample input and output directly in the question, formatted as code with four or more leading spaces on each line.

Comment: Please post the expected results here in the question. And only the expected results for the sample data provided.

Comment: Fiddles and desired results are great, but paste them into the question too, so we don't have to navigate away from this page.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i edited my question and added the expected result in the question please check.The result is wrapped because of its length.

Comment: @KannanK unable to get your expected result, Please make clear I'll try to help you

Comment: @Irfan the expected result is wrapped because of not having enough space, there are three rows.

Comment: @KannanK make it in excel & attache a screenshot..

Comment: @Irfan download the file from this link to view the expected result:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YdMKuRhOWfmGU4chqx55NMaIx3IenNlT/view?usp=sharing Download the file to see the result clearly and properly aligned.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887626/sub-columns-in-mysql?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @KannanK, I think you need to do something manually, You can get 22 columns by query

Comment: It is not clear what your "expected result" is supposed to be. Apparently you want one table, so show us one table. Show us *exactly*. There are no nested/multi-line headings in MySQL. If that's what you want say so. Otherwise show your result the way it can be printed by MySQL. Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: @philipxy please download this file for expecting result. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YdMKuRhOWfmGU4chqx55NMaIx3IenNlT/view

Comment: Please read & act on [ask] & make your question self-contained, [including using text, not images/links, for text including tables](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Support of Stackoverflow users I found the solution for my question.

```
SELECT
    sid,
    NAME,
    housenu AS house_number,
    addr AS Address,
    htax AS Arrear_housetax,
    ltax AS Arrear_lighttax,
    gtax AS Arrear_garbagetax,
    chousetax AS Current_housetax,
    clighttax AS Current_lighttax,
    cgarbage AS Current_garbagetax,
    htax + chousetax AS totalhousetax,
    ltax + clighttax AS totallighttax,
    gtax + cgarbage AS totalgarbagetax,
    housetax_Ids,
    Garbagetax_ids,
    lighttax_Ids,
    htax_collected AS Collected_housetax,
    LTAX_collected AS Collected_lighttax,
    gtax_collected AS Collected_garbagetax,
    totalhousetax - htax_collected AS balance_housetax,
    totallighttax - LTAX_collected AS balance_Lighttax,
    totalgarbage - gtax_collected AS balance_garbagetax
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        sid,
        NAME,
        housenu,
        addr,
        gtax,
        htax,
        ltax,
        cgarbage,
        chousetax,
        clighttax,
        gtax + cgarbage AS totalgarbage,
        htax + chousetax AS totalhousetax,
        ltax + clighttax AS totallighttax,
        Garbagetax_ids,
        lighttax_Ids,
        housetax_Ids,
        gtax_collected,
        htax_collected,
        LTAX_collected
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            sid,
            c.consumer_name AS NAME,
            s.house_number AS housenu,
            c.address AS addr,
            SUM(
                CASE WHEN subincome = 'garbage tax' THEN taxdue ELSE 0
            END
    ) - SUM(
        CASE WHEN subincome = 'garbage tax' THEN taxpaid ELSE 0
    END
) AS gtax,
SUM(
    CASE WHEN subincome = 'house tax' THEN taxdue ELSE 0
END
) - SUM(
    CASE WHEN subincome = 'house tax' THEN taxpaid ELSE 0
END
) AS htax,
SUM(
    CASE WHEN subincome = 'light tax' THEN taxdue ELSE 0
END
) - SUM(
    CASE WHEN subincome = 'light tax' THEN taxpaid ELSE 0
END
) AS ltax,
cgarbage,
chousetax,
clighttax,
Garbagetax_ids,
lighttax_Ids,
housetax_Ids,
gtax_collected,
htax_collected,
LTAX_collected
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        F.`house_number`,
        F.`year`,
        F.`house_tax` taxdue,
        F.`createdAt`,
        F.`updatedAt`,
        IFNULL(h.subincome, 'house_tax') subincome,
        IFNULL(H.RUPEES, 0) taxpaid
    FROM
        FINANCIAL_YEARS F
    LEFT JOIN house_details H ON
        H.HOUSE_ID = F.HOUSE_NUMBER AND H.SUBINCOME = 'house tax' AND f.year = h.financial_year
        #where f.house_number = 22
    UNION ALL
SELECT
    F.`house_number`,
    F.`year`,
    F.`light_tax`,
    F.`createdAt`,
    F.`updatedAt`,
    IFNULL(h.subincome, 'light tax'),
    IFNULL(H.RUPEES, 0)
FROM
    FINANCIAL_YEARS F
LEFT JOIN house_details H ON
    H.HOUSE_ID = F.HOUSE_NUMBER AND H.SUBINCOME = 'light tax' AND f.year = h.financial_year
    #where f.house_number = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT
    F.`house_number`,
    F.`year`,
    F.`garbage_tax`,
    F.`createdAt`,
    F.`updatedAt`,
    IFNULL(h.subincome, 'garbage tax'),
    IFNULL(H.RUPEES, 0)
FROM
    FINANCIAL_YEARS F
LEFT JOIN house_details H ON
    H.HOUSE_ID = F.HOUSE_NUMBER AND H.SUBINCOME = 'garbage tax' AND f.year = h.financial_year
    #where f.house_number = 2
) s
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT house_number,
        IFNULL(garbage_tax, 0) AS cgarbage,
        IFNULL(light_tax, 0) AS clighttax,
        IFNULL(house_tax, 0) AS chousetax
    FROM
        financial_years
    WHERE
        YEAR = "2017-2018"
) Y
ON
    s.house_number = Y.house_number
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
        house_id,
        GROUP_CONCAT(garbagetax_Ids) AS Garbagetax_ids,
        GROUP_CONCAT(lighttax_Ids) AS Lighttax_ids,
        GROUP_CONCAT(housetax_Ids) AS Housetax_ids
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            house_id,
            CASE WHEN subincome = 'Garbage tax' THEN receipt_id
    END AS garbagetax_Ids,
    CASE WHEN subincome = 'Light tax' THEN receipt_id
END AS lighttax_Ids,
CASE WHEN subincome = 'House tax' THEN receipt_id
END AS housetax_Ids
FROM
    house_details
) AS mm
GROUP BY
    house_id
) f
ON
    s.house_number = f.house_id
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
        house_id,
        SUM(gtax) AS gtax_collected,
        SUM(htax) AS htax_collected,
        SUM(LTAX) AS LTAX_collected
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            house_id,
            CASE WHEN h.subincome = 'Garbage tax' THEN SUM(h.rupees) ELSE 0
    END AS gtax,
    CASE WHEN h.subincome = 'House tax' THEN SUM(h.rupees) ELSE 0
END AS htax,
CASE WHEN h.subincome = 'Light tax' THEN SUM(h.rupees) ELSE 0
END AS LTAX
FROM
    house_details h
GROUP BY
    house_id,
    subincome
) AS main
GROUP BY
    house_id
) cf
ON
    s.house_number = cf.house_id

LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT house_number AS sid,
        consumer_name,
        address
    FROM
        consumer_details
) c
ON
    s.house_number = c.sid
WHERE
    s.year <> '2017-2018'
GROUP BY
    c.consumer_name,
    s.house_number,
    c.address
) az
) aa
```

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers are larger than you expect, then here is the explanation and a clue of what to do:

When `JOINing`, the number of intermediate rows is inflated.  A subsequent `GROUP BY` deflates the number of rows.  The trouble is that the aggregates (such as `SUM()`) are done with the inflated row count.

So the trick is to do the `SUMs` before doing the `JOIN`.  Try something like

```
SELECT ...  -- probably no SUM() needed here
    FROM ( SELECT financial_year, house_id,
                  SUM(...), SUM(...) ... FROM house_details
              GROUP BY 1,2 ) AS h
    JOIN ( SELECT year, house_number, 
                  SUM(...), SUM(...) ... FROM financial_years
              GROUP BY 1,2 ) AS f
        ON h.financial_year = f.year 
       AND h.house_id = f.house_number
```

I don't think you will need a `GROUP BY` on the end.

You may need an extra JOIN on the end to get `customer_name`, etc.  And an optional `ORDER BY customer_name`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've got.  It produces the correct results I believe:

```
SELECT c.consumer_id, c.consumer_name, c.house_number, c.address,
   SUM(GTAX) AS GTAX, SUM(HTAX) AS HTAX, SUM(LTAX) AS LTAX
FROM
(
SELECT c.address, c.consumer_id, c.consumer_name, c.house_number, hd.financial_year, 
  sum(ifnull(f.garbage_tax,0))-ifnull((SELECT SUM(RUPEES) RUPEES FROM house_details h WHERE hd.financial_year=h.financial_year and c.house_number=h.house_id and h.SUBINCOME='Garbage tax'),0) AS gtax, 
  sum(ifnull(f.house_tax,0))-ifnull((SELECT SUM(RUPEES) RUPEES FROM house_details h WHERE hd.financial_year=h.financial_year and  c.house_number=h.house_id and h.SUBINCOME='House tax'),0) AS htax, 
  sum(ifnull(f.light_tax,0))-ifnull((SELECT SUM(RUPEES) RUPEES FROM house_details h WHERE hd.financial_year=h.financial_year and  c.house_number=h.house_id and h.SUBINCOME='Light tax'),0) AS ltax 
from consumer_details c
cross join (select distinct hd.financial_year from house_details hd where hd.financial_year<>'2017-2018') hd
LEFT OUTER JOIN financial_years f ON c.house_number=f.house_number and f.year=hd.financial_year
  where c.house_number in (select h.house_id from house_details h)
group by consumer_id, consumer_name, c.house_number, hd.financial_year
) c
group by c.consumer_id, c.consumer_name, c.house_number, c.address
        ,c.house_number
        ,c.address
```

Comment: i edited it to filter records that don't have house details just now.